# Devise login logout too slow for user model. Admin model works normally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I've used devise before without any problems on heroku. It is working fine, but the login and logout functions are going really slow. About 3 full seconds to work.

The only thing I've changed from the basic setup is the paths. I have a User table, so I changed the path to member:

```
devise_for :users, :path => "member", :path_names => { :sign_in =>
    'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :password => 'secret', :confirmation
    => 'verification', :unlock => 'unblock', :registration => 'register', :sign_up => 'signup' }
```

The log doesn't show anything, but it sometimes gives me an error when it takes too long:

```
Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

The admin model logs in and out quickly. The difference in the model is:

```
admin
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :trackable, :validatable, :timeoutable, :lockable

user
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :trackable, :validatable, :rememberable, :confirmable, :registerable
```

I tried removing rememberable from user and the logout become much faster, but login  still really slow.

I don't know how to give specifics as I don't think I've done anything else different, but would be happy to give more answers if there are other things that could help answer this.

Hopefully someone can help me out.

Comment: As a heads up, I took away the different path and renamed the user table to member. So it should be back to a baseline setup and is still running slower than it should be.